# How to get a Makefile to use the linker flags defined in a separate txt file?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am compiling and building a C code that needs some shared libraries(.so) during linking phase using a simple Makefile. I understand I could pass these library flags using variable LDFLAGS and place it just after OBJ files in the Makefile and get it to work.
However, in my case, I would be needing to compile several variations of the code that needs different shared libraries for linking with minimal changes to Makefile.

I saw a github submission such as below where they seem to use a txt file(named ldflags.txt) where they put the needed flags and the Makefile(this is where I need some help) seems to magically use the content of this file for linking.
https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-nRF528x-mbedos/blob/master/variants/ARDUINO_NANO33BLE/ldflags.txt

My question is, do we have a way to define the LDFLAGS in a separate file so that Makefile can make use of them? If possible, could you please share simple example.

Thanks.

Comment: Did my response answer your question? Would be nice if you accept it if it did.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `gcc` you can introduce command line switches, defines etc. via the `@file` option which is described in the last paragraph here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options. Allthough I'm not totally sure it looks like `clang` has the identical behaviour.

An example could look like this:

```
additional_flags := $(if $(build_debug),some/debug_flags.txt,other/nodebug_flags.txt)

LD_FLAGS := -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--wrap,main -Wl,--wrap,_malloc_r -Wl,--wrap,_free_r -Wl,--wrap,_realloc_r -Wl,--wrap,_memalign_r -Wl,--wrap,_calloc_r -Wl,--wrap,exit -Wl,--wrap,atexit -Wl,-n --specs=nano.specs -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -DMBED_ROM_START=0x8000000 -DMBED_ROM_SIZE=0x20000 -DMBED_RAM_START=0x20000000 -DMBED_RAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMBED_BOOT_STACK_SIZE=1024 -DXIP_ENABLE=0 
LD_SYS_LIBS :=-Wl,--start-group -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -lnosys  -Wl,--end-group


PREPROC = arm-none-eabi-cpp
PREPROC_FLAGS := -E -P -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--wrap,main -Wl,--wrap,_malloc_r -Wl,--wrap,_free_r -Wl,--wrap,_realloc_r -Wl,--wrap,_memalign_r -Wl,--wrap,_calloc_r -Wl,--wrap,exit -Wl,--wrap,atexit -Wl,-n --specs=nano.specs -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fmessage-length=0 -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -funsigned-char -MMD -fomit-frame-pointer -Og -DMBED_DEBUG -DMBED_TRAP_ERRORS_ENABLED=1 -DMBED_RTOS_SINGLE_THREAD -D__NEWLIB_NANO -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -DMBED_ROM_START=0x8000000 -DMBED_ROM_SIZE=0x20000 -DMBED_RAM_START=0x20000000 -DMBED_RAM_SIZE=0x8000 -DMBED_BOOT_STACK_SIZE=1024 -DXIP_ENABLE=0

LIBRARY_PATHS := $(addprefix -L,$(dir $(libmbed_lib) ))
LIBRARIES :=   $(addprefix -l, $(patsubst lib%.a,%,$(notdir $(libmbed_lib) )))
LINKER_SCRIPT ?= mbed-os/targets/TARGET_STM/TARGET_STM32F0/TARGET_STM32F091xC/TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM/STM32F091XC.ld
  

application.elf: application.o libmbed.lib ......
    +@echo "linking: $@"
    $(GCC_ARM) $(LD_FLAGS) -T ArduinoCore-nRF528x-mbedos/variants/ARDUINO_NANO33BLE/linker_script.ld $(LIBRARY_PATHS) --output app.elf $(src) $(LIBRARIES) $(LD_SYS_LIBS) $(LIBRARIES) @$(additional_flags)
    @echo Create bin: ------------------
    $(ELF2BIN) -O binary app.elf app.bin
```